Idempotent of a Banach algebra on the boundary of an ideal must belong to the ideal?
Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and $J$ be an ideal of it. If $1 \in \partial J,$ then there exists some point $x\in J$ such that $\|1-x\|<1/2,$ which means $x$ is invertible, and hence $1\in J.$
I am wondering whether the same thing holds for idempotents other than 1. Let $p$ be and idempotent $p=p^2$ in $\partial J.$ Does that always imply $p\in J$?

Observe that $pAp$ is a Banach subalgebra with unit equal $p.$ Assume $p$ belongs to $\partial J.$ Then there is $x\in J$ such that $\|p-x\|<{1\over \|p\|^2}.$ Therefore $$\|p-pxp\|=\|p^3-pxp\|=\|p(p-x)p\|<1$$ Thus $pxp$ is invertible in the subalgebra $pAp.$ Hence there exists $y\in pAp$ such that $y(pxp)=p.$ We get $p\in J$ as $pxp\in J.$
Remark It could be interesting to decide whether the conclusion holds for left ideals (or right ideals). The answer above doesn't cover these cases.

OP asks if $p \in J$, not $1 \in J$. Your $p$ does belong to $J$.

@geetha290krm Thanks. I have corrected the answer. Hopefully it is correct.

Why is this a partial answer? Isn't it a complete answer?

Usually the ideal is meant as $xy\in J$ for any $x\in J$ and $y\in A.$ In my answer u I use that also $yx\in J.$ This the case 1

@RyszardSzwarc Oh I think an ideal means a two-sided ideal. Does Banach algebras use a different convention?

OK. I will remove the  sentence "partial answer". Still your problem is interesting for one sided ideals. For  instance left ideal where you assume that $xy\in J$ whenever $x\in A$ and $y\in J.$,
